# Treat remote http URLs as local ones

Tags: android, http, url, httpserver, dlna

I don't know how to call it correctly and how to do it, but I will try to explain what I want to achieve.

Remote server provides URLs to mp3 files (downloadable) like so:
http://someremotehost.com/song1.mp3

I need this link to be local, for example:
http://192.168.0.20:78787/song1.mp3

So that I could send the local URL to my DLNA player, which would understand it as a local URL, though the mp3 file would be played from remote host.

One of my ideas was to setup a http server that would map somehow remote URL to local ones, possibly downloading mp3 files from remote host and providing a URL of it on hard disk. But I'm not good at such things, so I wonder what are the options and how to do it right.

It is an Android app I'm developing, so I would appreciate approaches that could easily fit within an app.

Thank you

Comment: `to setup a http server that would map somehow remote URL to local ones`. No. That would map local ones to remote ones.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Then that is not what I want. Do you know any other options?